# When is it appropriate to pass a collection to a backbone model constructor second argument?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When is it appropriate to pass a collection to a backbone model constructor? as in

```
var someColl = new SomeCollection();
var m = new SomeModel({}, {collection: someColl});
```

the model constructor queries the 2nd arg for a collection property and if it exists, it is assigned to the model collection property. Otherwise these items are attached the constructor function I believe.  Are there any examples of when and why you would do these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var someColl = new SomeCollection()
var m = someColl.create({ foo: bar })

# m.collection == someColl
```

If you call [`create`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-create) on the collection you will receive the newly created model (which was also added to collection). From then on you can reference the collection whenever you need it with `m.collection`

I think referencing a collection on the model makes the most sense in this scenario. You're adding a new model to a collection, and since it intrinsically belongs within it, it makes sense to reference it with `.collection`.

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes found it useful to pass the parent view a model gets instantiated in. Albeit that's very rare, you can easily do something like `new TabModel(null, {tabGroupView: this});` . I wouldn't say it's a pattern I would use much, but it's definitely handy to pass options around. That's what I like about Backbone, you're more free to do whatever you like.